# How to read VMware interrupt backlog?

Tags: vmware-esxi, time, time-synchronization, clock-synchronization

The VMware document titled "[Timekeeping in VMware Virtual Machines](https://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/techpaper/Timekeeping-In-VirtualMachines.pdf)" have the following referente to the issues with the time drift:

> If the virtual machine is running too slowly, perhaps as a result of competition for CPU time from other virtual
>   machines or processes running on the host machine, it might be impossible to feed the virtual machine enough
>   interrupts to keep up with real time. In current VMware products, if the backlog of interrupts grows beyond 60
>   seconds, the virtual machine gives up on catching up, simply setting its record of the backlog to zero.

Where is this backlog counter and how can I read it to monitor this behaviour?

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Comment: Be aware that the doc you point to is several years old.    Vmware (and linux distributions) have changed since then.  See https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1006427

Comment: I agree with @DanPritts, you shouldn't have any timekeeping problems with somewhat current Linux versions... and we're not talking about the latest versions, RHEL6 and SLES11 are already quite old in my view.

Comment: Monitor this behaviour is helpfull because the recomendations only cover the issue, not fix the origin of the problem. Maybe the ntp is fixing the time frequently because there are a lot of vm in a host, in this case, the time is right, but the issue is in the background.

Comment: Note that if you stop using vmware tools, the interrupt disruption certainly under windows vms goes down dramatically. It goes down from 20% cpu usage to practically zero. There's something very wrong with VMware tools!